# Linux : Very slow internet connections through proxy

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, apt, yum, proxy

I am experiencing very slow Internet connections for applications like apt-get and Firefox browsing through proxy (download speed in Firefox is pretty normal). My Internet connection uses a proxy system ( I think SQUID PROXY)with username and password authentication. I have tried to put proxy settings in apt.conf or .bashrc or like adding proxy environment in /etc/sudoers. Git clone speed is pretty normal. At the same time the speeds are rocketing 100 times than linux in windows.  (tried it in fedora also...Same problem)

Comment: Slowdown of the internet connection is to be expected when you are running through a proxy, regardless of the OS. The same would apply to VPN as well. Whatever speed limitation there may be on the proxy, is going to be applied to your internet connection whenever you use the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

> tried it in fedora also...Same problem

Simple: there is no problem on your machine. You're trying to fix a problem which does not exist, at least not where you're trying to fix it.

As you know, when using a proxy, you change your network transaction from...

```
YOU   <===>  INTERNET   <===>   TARGET
```

... to...

```
YOU   <===>  INTERNET   <===>  PROXY  <===>   INTERNET  <===>  TARGET
```

This means that when communicating over the network, your messages go through more machines. This also means that it can get into more trouble. Plus, the more machines you add, the more "relaying" is necessary, and the more time it takes to reach your destination.

You're basically facing network latency, which isn't really a "bug". It's more of a "natural behaviour". You could try using another proxy, with a better network environment around it, but there's nothing to prevent the problem from re-occuring eventually.

Comment: I'm not using any vpn service (like Hidemyass). Rather My college has a proxy system to access the internet.
It may be said as :
ME  <===> Proxy via Ethernet <===> INTERNET <===> TARGET
And even if it is so .... Why is it faster in Windows??